# Rails 4 and declarative_authorization gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, bundler, gemfile, declarative-authorization

I'm trying to use declarative_authorization gem within my Rails 4 app but after inserting it within my gemfile `gem 'declarative_authorization'` and run the `bundle` command I try to install it with the command

```
rails g authorization:install UserModel=Professional nome email telefone logradouro numero bairro cep cidade estado profissao tutorial_completo plan_id:index status_id:index --create-user --user-belongs-to-role
```

but I get the error `Could not find generator authorization:install.`

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: The project seems dead... https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization/issues/192

Comment: not so dead - they merged some rails 4 support in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it get the gem straight from the github repo.  I had this same problem and I had a version that was before they added the installer.  When I made it fetch the gem from github it got a later version and the installer worked

```
#Gemfile
gem 'declarative_authorization', github: "stffn/declarative_authorization"
```